# Subclipse SVNKit installs, but doesn't run in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, svnkit

I've successfully installed Subclipse through Eclipse's *Help* > *Install New Software...*.

When I go to *Java* perspective > *Package Explorer* view > *Team* > *Share Project* and select *SVN*, I get:

> org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: The path '\path\to\project' appears to be part of Subversion 1.7 (SVNKit 1.4) or greater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a problem with version mismatch, get a [proper version](http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x) of subclipse

From subclipse site:

> News
>
> Subversion 1.7.0 Support Subclipse 1.8.x releases are now available
>   and includes support for Subversion 1.7.0 including the new WC-NG
>   format.

You might have to uninstall the previous version of subclipse (and SVNKit) before installing the new version.